# How to know the module from front end?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

We are creating a German language website. I am using a language pack for translation. But it does not conform to the dialect. So we have to change some translations. But I dont know which one to change depending on the page.
For ex: I need "Qty" to be named as "St." in some pages and "Stück" in some pages.

And I cannot identify which module translation to be changed for this.

Is there a way to identify the module from front end? Sorry I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I faced such a problem, I tried a lot of things, a lot of so-called (Developers) tried to solve this problem, but the guys from https://barwenock.com/ helped me, they are a real professional in their field, I recommend))